How to start and deploy DFX 0.9.3 in VSCode?
This is the error I get:

Error:cannot parse provider URL
Caused by:invalid port number.

I have tried almost everything, but I could not find any solution.
dfx replica --port,
dfx bootstrap --port,
dfx replica --port,
config {
  listern_add:127.0.0.1.0.port-file_path, 
  dfx info replica-port, 
  REPLICA_PORT=8000, 
  dfx start --clean

What can I do?

Please read the info on this link and then edit the question and add some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
